# Can I create/edit contact groups in iOS?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, contacts

I have been successful in managing contact groups with OS X's Contacts.app and iCloud.com, but haven't found a way to do this as of iOS 9.

**Is there a way to manage contact groups on iOS *(iPhone, iPad, or iPod Touch)* ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to create or edit contact groups on iOS. I share your frustration! The best workaround is to use iCloud.com (or your primary Mac, if you have it with you).

Also, there *is* a way to add contacts to a specific group on iOS, though it's not obvious:

1. In Contacts, tap the Groups button in the top left
2. Tap "Hide All Contacts"
3. Tap the group that you want to add the contact to (making it the only visible group)
4. Tap Done in the top right
5. Tap the Add button (`+`) in the top right

Now when you create and save the contact, it'll save it in that specific group. You can then go back to the Groups list and reenable all your groups.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple and yet dissatisfactioning: NO (with standard apps).

EDIT: There are some apps on the AppStore which enable this feature. One of them is "Groups Free". At least it adds groups to my iCloud account.